# Are children books with pictures in them haram in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, children, books

I have a lot of books I used to read when I was a kid like diary of a wimpy kid and big Nate and I just recently found out things with pictures in them are haram so should I throw these books out or keep them?

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/71170 This may help.

Comment: You should consider deleting one of your posts [Are books with pictures in them haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/53238/are-books-with-pictures-in-them-haram). Note that as a registered user you may edit your posts for further information about our site and model take our [tour] and check our [help].

Comment: I checked that website and I think it talks mostly about toy animals and cartoons not exactly books I didn’t read the entire thing but I read most of it

Answer (score 1):

Personally I suggest that anything with images should not be associated with you since it prevents the angles from visiting your home & we Muslims know that creating images is haram because only Allah creates things which we can't mimic or compare, it is also seen as a disobedience and challenge to God.

Comment: Ok thanks may Allah bless your soul

Comment: I appreciate the kind words and feedback. By the way It’s the same ruling on books. Jzk